# ATG - Build error caused by packages not found

Tags: eclipse, atg

I'm trying to build an ATG's project on Eclipse, and it occurs the following errors:

```
error: package org.apache.axis2 does not exist
error: package org.apache.axiom.om does not exist
```

Despite of the presence of the above packages inside the project, the build is not recognizing them. What should be the problem?

I also can see their JARs referenced on Project properties' Libraries section. Among other dozens of packages only the above ones can't be found.

Comment: Give more details like project structure, how you build it like using eclipse or ant or gradle,etc

Comment: As Santosh mentioned your project is using a build tool. e.g.: In my case I have to put jar names in MANIFEST files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Any Jar reference used in the workspace should be put in the
   Eclipse project build path.
2. Path of the jars used should be put
   under the ClassPath dependencies property in the MANIFEST.MF files.
3. If the above two are not working, then clean the workspace, close
   the workspace and try to launch eclipse again. Though this solution
   is weird, it works best !!